# How do I get a Registration object to register Classroom API for notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, push-notification, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I am attempting to have my Google Classroom API enable push notifications. I have successfully created a topic in Cloud Pub/Sub to have this work. But the docs are officially confusing me on the part where I'm supposed to get a `Registration` object to pass to `Classroom#registrations().create()`.

I have been looking at the docs for a little while now, and I can't find the place where a Registration should be instantiated. Perhaps I don't understand the concept well enough. I would highly appreciate someone's further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I'm such a silly goose. I put more effort into reading the docs, and this finally clicked.

I'm using Java.
registrations().create takes a Registration object, which is just a representation of a JSON REST Registration object in the API. It's just an abstraction to be used in the client library. [This is a good place to get you started understanding this](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations#Registration)

Here's some example code I wrote now that I understand how this works:

```java
NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
Classroom service = buildClassroomService(httpTransport);

final var pubSupTopic = new CloudPubsubTopic()
        .setTopicName("my-topic");

final var courseWorkChangesInfo = new CourseRosterChangesInfo()
        .setCourseId("------------");

final var feed = new Feed()
        .setFeedType("COURSE_WORK_CHANGES")
        .setCourseRosterChangesInfo(courseWorkChangesInfo);

Registration notificationsRegistration = new Registration()
        .setFeed(feed)
        .setCloudPubsubTopic(pubSupTopic);

pubSupTopic.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
courseWorkChangesInfo.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
feed.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
notificationsRegistration.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);

final var response = service.registrations().create(notificationsRegistration);
```